# Html/CSS/Javascript: Popup onclick not working for second div

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am opening up a small popup box when a `div` is selected. It works, but if I try to do this a second time (shown below), it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help you can provide, it is greatly appreciated. Here is my code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp):

HTML:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
  Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction2()">
  Click me2!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Popup text...2</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var popup =
    document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction2() {
  var popup =
    document.getElementById("myPopup2");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

CSS:

```
/* Popup container */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup 
     container (hide and show the popup) */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s
}
```

Comment: You have two functions with the same name.... `myFunction()` so you are basically overwriting the first one with the second one.

Comment: you have two functions named the same ... how do you expect the click to know which one you want to run .... hint: only the second function actually exists anyway

Comment: Are you wanting to only display one `popuptext` at a time? You could use `javascript` to set `click` event handlers for all elements with the `class` of `popup` and you will only need to write one function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myFunction` is declared twice and the second one is overriding the first one.

change it to `myFunction2` or whatever an them update your `onclick="myFunction2()"`

It is always good to check your console for errors :)

```js
 function myFunction() {
   var popup = 
   document.getElementById("myPopup");
   popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }
   function myFunction2() {
   var popup = 
   document.getElementById("myPopup2");
   popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Popup container */
 .popup {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 /* The actual popup (appears on top) */
 .popup .popuptext {
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 160px;
 background-color: #555;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 8px 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 125%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -80px;
 }

 /* Popup arrow */
 .popup .popuptext::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -5px;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #555 transparent transparent 
 transparent;
 }

 /* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup 
 container (hide and show the popup) */
 .popup .show {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
 animation: fadeIn 1s
 }
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click 
me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup 
   text...</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction2()">Click 
me2!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Popup 
   text...2</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hey @caiovisk, thanks for the help and tips. I tried what you recommended, but for some reason, it is still not working. :/ I edited the above code with your recommendation

Comment: I place your code on the snippet and it is working... what is not working on your end?

Comment: Not the best solution to offer. Why not iterate through `class` of `popup` and set a `click` event handler? This one mean one function deals with multiple elements with the same functionality expectations rather than  having to copy/paste the function and rename it for each element you want to use it on....

Comment: Hey there, that sounds like a good idea but I am not sure how to do that. I am very nice but will try to figure it out by researching.

Comment: @caiovisk - I think something else is going on. I literally have it copied and pasted. It must be something on my end. The second popup text isn't working but the first is... so weird.

Comment: @AndrewK open your browser console and check for errors.

Comment: Figured it out - had another function named the same. Wow oh wow. Lesson learned. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine.

```css
/* Popup container */
 .popup {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 /* The actual popup (appears on top) */
 .popup .popuptext {
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 160px;
 background-color: #555;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 8px 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 125%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -80px;
 }

 /* Popup arrow */
 .popup .popuptext::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -5px;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #555 transparent transparent 
 transparent;
 }

 /* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup 
 container (hide and show the popup) */
 .popup .show {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
 animation: fadeIn 1s
 }
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click 
me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup 
   text...</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction2()">Click 
me2!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Popup 
   text...2</span>
 </div>
 <script>
   function myFunction() {
   var popup = 
   document.getElementById("myPopup");
   popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }
   function myFunction2() {
   var popup = 
   document.getElementById("myPopup2");
   popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by adding click event using javascript only.
Using this, you can add as many as popup element.

```js
  var popupArr = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");
  for (var index in popupArr) {
      popupArr[index].onclick = function(ev) {
          var popup = ev.target.children[0];
          popup.classList.toggle("show");
      }
  }
```

```css
/* Popup container */
 .popup {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 /* The actual popup (appears on top) */
 .popup .popuptext {
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 160px;
 background-color: #555;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 8px 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 125%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -80px;
 }

 /* Popup arrow */
 .popup .popuptext::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -5px;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #555 transparent transparent 
 transparent;
 }

 /* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup 
 container (hide and show the popup) */
 .popup .show {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
 animation: fadeIn 1s
 }
```

```html
<div class="popup">Click 
me!
  <span class="popuptext" >Popup 
   text...</span>
</div>

<div class="popup">Click 
me2!
  <span class="popuptext" >Popup 
   text...2</span>
 </div>
```